# RegEx Trouble, ignore trailing ]

Tags: regex

I am parsing a log file with 3 variations of a line and I'm trying to build a regex that matches and groups all variations.

Here are the line variations:

```
StatementId: [12345], UserId: 8756

StatementId: 12345, UserId: 8756

StatementId: [12345,6789], UserId: 8756
```

The current expression I have matches all cases, except #3.

I am expecting 2 groups. Using the lines above, the first group would be either 12345 or 12345,6789 The second group would simply be 8756

The problem I'm having is with line variation #3. The closing bracket ] being included in the first matching group.

Thus for line #3 the first group result is:

```
12345,6789]
```

I'm using this site for testing:

https://regex101.com/

Here is my regex:

```
(?:StatementId: \[?)(.*)(?:\]?, .*UserId: )([0-9]*)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

I've attempted the suggested non-greedy solution(s) in several variations but that doesn't appear to solve the problem.

The expression variations I've tried will work on a single line variation, but not on all 3.

**SOLUTION**:

[sln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557597/sln) in the comments had 2 suggested solutions, both of which work.

Comment: Use `.*?` instead of `.*`.

Comment: Get rid of the confusion: `StatementId: \[?(.*?)\]?,.*UserId: ([0-9]*)`

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor, but I've tried that and it does not resolve the issue of the closing bracket always being included in the first group, at least when using the regex101.com testing site.

Comment: @sln that expression only appears to match the first statementId in the comma delimited list for group 1

Comment: Use a branch reset or use an extra capture group `StatementId:[ ](?|\[([^\[\]]*)\]|(.*?)),.*UserId:[ ]([0-9]*)` https://regex101.com/r/gX8qK6/1 or https://regex101.com/r/gX8qK6/2

Comment: Thanks @sln that works great!

Comment: @sln Please post your solutions.

Comment: Other possible way: `StatementId: \[?\K[^]\s]*[^]\s,]` https://regex101.com/r/gE9nV1/1 or more simple `StatementId: \[?\K[0-9,]*[0-9]` https://regex101.com/r/gE9nV1/3

Comment: @Casimir that works as well thanks! The one tweak I didn't mention is that sometimes there will be a space between the statement ids, but just a small change to your solution handles that as well: `StatementId: \[?\K[0-9, ?]*[0-9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a Branch Reset `(?|..)` which reuses the capture groups
http://www.regex101.com/r/gX8qK6/1

`StatementId:[ ](?|\[([^\[\]]*)\]|(.*?)),.*UserId:[ ]([0-9]*)`

```
 StatementId: [ ] 
 (?|
      \[
      ( [^\[\]]* )                  # (1)
      \]
   |  
      ( .*? )                       # (1)
 )
 , .* UserId: [ ] 
 ( [0-9]* )                    # (2)
```

or,

Not use branch reset, which converts the group to an extra capture group
for the two cases of with/without `[]`
http://www.regex101.com/r/gX8qK6/2

(*Note- this case is an exclusive capture.

Means you can blindly concatenate groups 1 & 2 to form the string.*)

`StatementId:[ ](?:\[([^\[\]]*)\]|(.*?)),.*UserId:[ ]([0-9]*)`

```
 StatementId: [ ] 
 (?:
      \[
      ( [^\[\]]* )                  # (1)
      \]
   |  
      ( .*? )                       # (2)
 )
 , .* UserId: [ ] 
 ( [0-9]* )                    # (3)
```

Comment: One final comment on this. I was using this in a small Java application and I ultimately had to use solution #2 (extra capture group) because I was getting this exception with solution #1: `Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 18


StatementId:[ ](?|\[([^\[\]]*)\]|(.*?)),.*UserId:[ ]([0-9]*)`


Which is referencing the pipe character | in the branch reset clause